# Will laptop Dell Inspiron 15 7000 gaming 7567 work with Ubuntu?

Tags: dell, laptop, inspiron

I am planning to buy a laptop that meets my requirements and is compatible with Linux,this one meets my desired requirements, but will it run Linux Ubuntu or no?

Dell Inspiron 7567 is said to be certificated, but I'm not sure if this applies to gaming edition, here is the laptop:

> [https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Inspiron-Gaming-15-6-Inch-Screen/dp/B071JPYP1Z/ref=sr_1_4?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1529590268&sr=1-4&keywords=Dell+inspiron+7567](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071JPYP1Z)

Comment: Generally speaking from personal experience, aside from potential graphic issues on extended monitors with Nvidia graphics card, otherwise everything seems to work fine for Dell Inspiron Series (I used it at work)

Comment: Many Dell posts, not sure if any your model. But they need RAID changed to AHCI, nomodeset boot parameter until nVidia driver installed from Ubuntu repository or ppa, and perhaps a few other settings. Most also needed UEFI update from Dell, even if new. NVMe drives are supported but also need firmware updates, this user had issue. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342359

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the specs, you shouldn't have any problem.

> Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Series Gaming Edition 7567 15.6-Inch Full HD
>   Screen Laptop - Intel Core i5-7300HQ, 1 TB Hybrid HDD, 8GB DDR4
>   Memory, NVIDIA GTX 1050 4GB Graphics, Windows 10

This specs is very similar to my Yoga 720 with GTX 1050 except that the Yoga has NVMe store and this one has a hybrid drive. I have no issue running Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 on mine.

If you plan to do dual boot with UEFI installation, make sure the drive is configured as AHCI, then in Windows shink the drive to allow space for Ubuntu installation. You can then use both the Linux grub2 and windows EFI boot manager to boot both OSes.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to let you know I've   my Inspiron 15 7000 for about 3 months, with Ubuntu 18.04, no problems so far, working quite well, the only thing I would suggest is to add an extra 8Gb of RAM.